# Compile OpenGL code using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu, x11

I need to compile this OpenGL stuff on QT Creator but I do not know that I added libraries:X11 and GL..

Ah, I am on Ubuntu Linux 64bit 12.04LTS.

When I compile, it shows a following Error:

```
:-1: error: [Makefile] Error 3
```

This code compiled and worked fine on Code Blocks IDE once after I added X11 and GL library.. but it seem it do not work on QT Creator IDE...

How to fix it??

---

Here is .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console

CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp


unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += X11

unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += GL
```

and Here is C++ File:

```
/* A simple program to show how to set up an X window for OpenGL rendering.
 * X86 compilation: gcc -o -L/usr/X11/lib   main main.c -lGL -lX11
 * X64 compilation: gcc -o -L/usr/X11/lib64 main main.c -lGL -lX11
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glx.h>    /* this includes the necessary X headers */
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <X11/X.h>    /* X11 constant (e.g. TrueColor) */
#include <X11/keysym.h>

static int snglBuf[] = {GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, None};
static int dblBuf[]  = {GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None};

Display   *dpy;
Window     win;
GLfloat    xAngle = 42.0, yAngle = 82.0, zAngle = 112.0;
GLboolean  doubleBuffer = GL_TRUE;

void fatalError(char *message)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "main: %s\n", message);
  exit(1);
}

void redraw(void)
{
  static GLboolean   displayListInited = GL_FALSE;

  if (displayListInited)
  {
    /* if display list already exists, just execute it */
    glCallList(1);
  }
  else
  {
    /* otherwise compile and execute to create the display list */
    glNewList(1, GL_COMPILE_AND_EXECUTE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* front face */
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glColor3f(0.0, 0.7, 0.1);  /* green */
      glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

      /* back face */
      glColor3f(0.9, 1.0, 0.0);  /* yellow */
      glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

      /* top side face */
      glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);  /* blue */
      glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);

      /* bottom side face */
      glColor3f(0.7, 0.0, 0.1);  /* red */
      glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glEnd();
    glEndList();
    displayListInited = GL_TRUE;
  }
  if (doubleBuffer)
    glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win);/* buffer swap does implicit glFlush */
  else
    glFlush();  /* explicit flush for single buffered case */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  XVisualInfo         *vi;
  Colormap             cmap;
  XSetWindowAttributes swa;
  GLXContext           cx;
  XEvent               event;
  GLboolean            needRedraw = GL_FALSE, recalcModelView = GL_TRUE;
  int                  dummy;

  /*** (1) open a connection to the X server ***/

  dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if (dpy == NULL)
    fatalError("could not open display");

  /*** (2) make sure OpenGL's GLX extension supported ***/

  if(!glXQueryExtension(dpy, &dummy, &dummy))
    fatalError("X server has no OpenGL GLX extension");

  /*** (3) find an appropriate visual ***/

  /* find an OpenGL-capable RGB visual with depth buffer */
  vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), dblBuf);
  if (vi == NULL)
  {
    vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), snglBuf);
    if (vi == NULL) fatalError("no RGB visual with depth buffer");
    doubleBuffer = GL_FALSE;
  }
  if(vi->c_class != TrueColor)
    fatalError("TrueColor visual required for this program");

  /*** (4) create an OpenGL rendering context  ***/

  /* create an OpenGL rendering context */
  cx = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, /* no shared dlists */ None,
                        /* direct rendering if possible */ GL_TRUE);
  if (cx == NULL)
    fatalError("could not create rendering context");

  /*** (5) create an X window with the selected visual ***/

  /* create an X colormap since probably not using default visual */
  cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, vi->screen), vi->visual, AllocNone);
  swa.colormap = cmap;
  swa.border_pixel = 0;
  swa.event_mask = KeyPressMask    | ExposureMask
                 | ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask;
  win = XCreateWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, vi->screen), 0, 0,
                      300, 300, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput, vi->visual,
                      CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask, &swa);
  XSetStandardProperties(dpy, win, "main", "main", None,
                         argv, argc, NULL);

  /*** (6) bind the rendering context to the window ***/

  glXMakeCurrent(dpy, win, cx);

  /*** (7) request the X window to be displayed on the screen ***/

  XMapWindow(dpy, win);

  /*** (8) configure the OpenGL context for rendering ***/

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); /* enable depth buffering */
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);    /* pedantic, GL_LESS is the default */
  glClearDepth(1.0);       /* pedantic, 1.0 is the default */

  /* frame buffer clears should be to black */
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  /* set up projection transform */
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0);
  /* establish initial viewport */
  /* pedantic, full window size is default viewport */
  glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

  printf( "Press left mouse button to rotate around X axis\n" );
  printf( "Press middle mouse button to rotate around Y axis\n" );
  printf( "Press right mouse button to rotate around Z axis\n" );
  printf( "Press ESC to quit the application\n" );

  /*** (9) dispatch X events ***/

  while (1)
  {
    do
    {
      XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
      switch (event.type)
      {
        case KeyPress:
        {
          KeySym     keysym;
          XKeyEvent *kevent;
          char       buffer[1];
          /* It is necessary to convert the keycode to a
           * keysym before checking if it is an escape */
          kevent = (XKeyEvent *) &event;
          if (   (XLookupString((XKeyEvent *)&event,buffer,1,&keysym,NULL) == 1)
              && (keysym == (KeySym)XK_Escape) )
            exit(0);
          break;
        }
        case ButtonPress:
          recalcModelView = GL_TRUE;
          switch (event.xbutton.button)
          {
            case 1: xAngle += 10.0;
              break;
            case 2: yAngle += 10.0;
              break;
            case 3: zAngle += 10.0;
              break;
          }
          break;
        case ConfigureNotify:
          glViewport(0, 0, event.xconfigure.width,
                     event.xconfigure.height);
          /* fall through... */
        case Expose:
          needRedraw = GL_TRUE;
          break;
      }
    } while(XPending(dpy)); /* loop to compress events */

    if (recalcModelView)
    {
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

      /* reset modelview matrix to the identity matrix */
      glLoadIdentity();

      /* move the camera back three units */
      glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);

      /* rotate by X, Y, and Z angles */
      glRotatef(xAngle, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
      glRotatef(yAngle, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0);
      glRotatef(zAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

      recalcModelView = GL_FALSE;
      needRedraw = GL_TRUE;
    }
    if (needRedraw)
    {
      redraw();
      needRedraw = GL_FALSE;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There simply must be more verbose compiler and possibly linker output. make errors aren't compiler errors. make simply invoke the compiler front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot actually see where you added the opengl to the core.
Please try adding

```
QT       += core gui opengl
```

To your .pro file.

p.s. I am not well aware of Linux, but I hope it somehow  will help you.

Comment: I have 2 suggestions:
1. Check your makefile itself, probably there are some extra spaces (makefile is space sensitive, NEVER edit it manually).
2. In .pro file check your sources and headers, if no extra staff is trying to be called (e.g. you have deleted some .cpp or .h file manually before). Then clean the project and rebuild it.

p.s. 2-nd case is more preferable not to blow your project up.